# she kicked me right in the teeth. Is there a pun in this phrase?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, pun

[image]

dialogue of an NPC in the game.

> I ran forward into the crowd, yelling for them to stop, but… I… I tripped and fell in the mud. I looked up and saw the face of a kindly grandmother. I reached for her hand and…**she kicked me right in the teeth**.

players reaction options.

> 1.That's horrible
>     2.You got beat up by an old woman?

if you choose 2, response is:

> You may think this is funny now, but it was devastating at the time.

picture comes from a PC game.

Is there a pun here? (the idiom "a kick in the teeth")

Or simply mean a real kick in the face?

Comment: Is it a character that now has no teeth as he tells the story from long ago? It would explain the statement "it's funny now but it wasn't funny back then".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**NO, there is not a pun**

As has already been explained, "*a kick in the teeth*" is a fairly common expression which figuratively means someone has *betrayed* you.

However in your example it actually says "*she kicked me **right in** the teeth*". This makes it very specific, and actually implies that it was a *literal* kick in the teeth. This is further evidenced by the detailed description - the person was lying on the floor and reached up to someone else to help them, but they kicked them in the teeth, which would be logistically possible in that position. If it wasn't for this additional context I might have wondered if it was a bad translation of the idiom "a kick in the teeth", but as it is I believe it is meant *literally*.

Comment: By my recollection of the game in question, it's definitely meant literally. Lots of Linu's dialogue is about the disastrous consequences of her extreme unluckiness/physical clumsiness.

Comment: I definitely agree that she was kicked, literally. However, I think it's arguable that it *can* be considered a pun. The desciption builds up the idea of a kind grandmother she needed help from - but instead betrayed/assaulted her (as per the metaphorical meaning of a "kick in the teeth"). I'd argue that double meaning is a perfect example of a good pun.

Comment: thanks a lot. Since most of you guys think it is literally then it is. Linu fell in the mud.Her face can be kicked without effort. It is not a situation so complex and need to be figurative here.

Comment: +1.Just would like to add that "you may think this is funny now" doesn't mean that there was some pun in the original phrase, but just that the player's reaction, "you got beat up by an old woman?", looks like an attempt to mock.

Comment: @Bilkokuya I half agree with you. I think a "pun" is strictly intentional, and meant to be funny. I don't think there is any intentional humour to be derived from the duality of meaning. However I think its a possibility that the writer knew of the idiom and used it ironically. The whole scenario is like the metaphor has been literally played out.

Answer (score 5):

The word **right** there means  "directly, not to any degree indirectly" or "precisely" or "exactly".

> He stepped right in a pile of dog-shit.
>
> The train arrived right on time.
>
> You can put the letter right on that table there beside you.
>
> Tell me where it hurts. Here?
>   --No.
>   Here?
>   --No.
>   Here?
>   --Ouch! Yes, right there.

So, **she kicked me right in the teeth** literally means that gave him or her a kick directly in the mouth.

I assume you are asking about a "pun" because of the phrase *You may think this is funny now...*. I do not see any sort of pun but a reversal of the kindly grandmother stereotype and *mockery* in player response #2, *You got beat up by an old woman?* The phrase **to get beat(en) up** means to be struck multiple times, again and again. Bullies beat people up, for example. The game's question #2 does not accurately reflect what happened in that regard, and it mocks the victim by implying that he or she was overcome and defeated in a fight by an old woman who was presumably physically weak.  That is why the game replies "You may think this is *funny* now...". A person who mocks an injured victim in that manner would probably be laughing derisively. At the very least they see humor in the situation. The victim does not find it funny.

Comment: because there is an idiom "a kick in the teeth" which actually no literally kicking involved.

Comment: @oyss: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. I need a main clause.

Answer (score 1):

After reading other answers, I have to say this is certainly **literal**, but not for the reason people are claiming.  The idiom is:

> **a kick** in the teeth

Note that the word **kick** is a noun in this context.

When switched from a noun to an active verb, the sentence suddenly becomes more visceral, more real, and thus takes on the literal meaning:

> She kicked me in the teeth.

In general, adding words like "right" for emphasis to these types of idioms describing physical actions does not change the meaning, it simply makes it stronger.

> He hit the nail on the head --> He hit the nail **right** on the head.
>
> Her response was a kick in the teeth --> Her response was a kick **straight** in the teeth.

The above phrases retain their idiomatic meaning even with the addition of the emphasis words in the middle.  It is the **grammatical** change that shifts the tone from idiomatic to literal in this case.